# how to add (subscribe?) all the plans to a user's calendar?

Tags: calendar, office365

I have to manage about 200 plans in planner, and need to view them in the calendar (for multiple users), but the interface is not really made for doing that, because there is not way to search for plans or to view them in a list.
Is there a way to do this for all the plans at once? Via ui, via graph api, via powershell, whatever way it could work...